# Find in dictionary in Mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I have to find in dictionary in a mongo database.

```
    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int,string> AgePersons { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried two options:

```
  _database.Find(v => v.Name == "test" && v.AgePersons.Any(el => el.Key == 12 && el.Value == "person_name")).ToList();
```

I got the error: The expression tree is not supported: {document}{dc}'

```
  _database.Find(v => v.Name == "test" && v.AgePersons[12] == "person_name"]).ToList();
```

I got the error: 'v.AgePersons.get_Item(12) is not supported.'

[image]

How can I solve?

Comment: Can you show how your document looks in the database?

Comment: yes, I already added

Answer (score 0):

A simple option would be to store your objects as:

```
public class Document
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<Item> People { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public String Key { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then map your data on read/write between your classes and these.

A perhaps better option would be to reshape your data when storing into:

```
public class Item
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Key { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then searching for a `Name` by `Key` and `Value` will be a lot easier and you can still collect the `Item`s into a single object by querying by name or by aggregating and using groupBy name as the last step in the pipeline.

This would also enabling simpler adding or removing of single items without altering large documents.